# How do function parameters correspond to each other after conversion between different functions?

Tags: c

I have a piece of code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*FUNC_TYPE)(int value, int count, int* pt);

void func(int* ptr, int val, int cnt, int* pd)
{
    printf("ptr: %p, %d \n", ptr, *ptr);
    printf("cnt: %p, %d \n", &cnt, cnt);
    printf("val: %p, %d \n", &val, val);
    printf("pd: %p, %d \n", pd, *pd);
}
int main()
{
    int val = 10;
    int tmp = 20;
    int* pd = &tmp;
    ((FUNC_TYPE)(func))(val, tmp, pd);
    return 0;
}
```

Results of passing arguments between functions in GDB is that:

```cpp
func (ptr=0xa, val=20, cnt=-73208, pd=0x14) at test.c:7
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

I want to know how to pass parameters between different types of functions in C language?

Comment: type of `FUNC_TYPE` need to be correspond to type of `func`, such as `typedef void (*FUNC_TYPE)(int value, int count, int* pt);` and `void func(int val, int cnt, int* pd)` is correct. And here you can directly use `func` function that don't use `typedef void (*FUNC_TYPE)(int value, int count, int* pt);`.

Comment: You lie to the compiler, you go in UB land...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `func` is not compatible with the function pointer type `FUNC_TYPE` because the number of arguments is not the same.

Casting a function pointer to an incompatible function pointer type and subsequently attempting to call the function through the converted pointer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

So you shouldn't be performing such conversions.